# Pagination of custom materialize projects does not work for me

Tags: jquery, html, materialize, materialized

The list of sub-pages does not work for me on the official demo sites:

1. [Materialized](http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v2.3/layout03/ui-pagination.html)
2. [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/pagination.html)(css)

Neither navigation bar changes the *active* page number (or content). Both websites use `materialize css`.

For an example, just click one of these links and confirm or prove me wrong please. Changing from Chrome 60 to Firefox 54 did not help. No content blockers are installed on Firefox.

Any ideas, if or why the framework has is erroneous?
Which browser plugin or corporate network feature could cause this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take the tour to see what and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please don't forget to add a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @marcogomes Updated. better? sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

The library does not contain handling of navigation (in JavaScript).
I will try adding something like
[materialize-pagination](https://mirjamsk.github.io/materialize-pagination/)

[Crossposted as github issue](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5036)